# Scala slick retrieve data tables in parallel

Tags: multithreading, scala, jdbc, slick

I need to read data from two different tables (both with above 100k rows) in the same database. So I tried to create two Futures and connection pool size is 50, but the performance doesn't seem to improve (total time around 5 seconds). Then I found  [this article](https://movio.co/blog/slick-for-database-access-in-scala/)

> So if you want to run multiple queries in parallel: no problem, just start them in separate Futures. However you won't have performance benefits, JDBC simply blocks a different Thread, not your main Thread of execution.

This means all the threads will be stuck at JDBC and processed sequentially. Is this true even if my connection pool size is 50? If yes, could you suggest an efficient way when dealing with data tables with large rows (such as load the data in less than 2 seconds)?

Here is my piece of code:

```
    case class User(name: String, age: Int)
    class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "User"){
      def user_id = column[Long]("user_id")
      def name = column[String]("user_name")
      def age = column[Int]("user_age")
      def * = (user_id, name, age) <> (
                { (row:(Long, String, Int)) => User(row._1, row._2, row._3)}
                { (p: User) => Some(p.name, p.age) }
               )
     }

    val users = TableQuery[User]

    case class Patron(name: String, type: Int)
    class Patron(tag: Tag) extends Table[Patron](tag, "Patron"){
      def patron_id = column[Long]("patron_id")
      def name = column[String]("patron_name")
      def type = column[Int]("patron_type")
      def * = (patron_id, name, type) <> (
                { (row:(Long, String, Int)) => User(row._1, row._2, row._3)}
                { (p: Patron) => Some(p.name, p.type) }
               )
    }

    val patrons = TableQuery[Patron]

    def getUsers(implicit session:Session): Future[Map[String, Int]] = Future {
      val allUserQuery = for (
        user <- users
      ) yield(user.name, user.age)

      allUserQuery.run.toMap
    }

   def getPatrons(implicit session:Session): Future[Map[String, Int]] = Future {
      val allPatronQuery = for (
        patron <- patrons
      ) yield(patron.name, patron.type)

      allPatronQuery.run.toMap
   }
   val (users: List[Map[String, Int]], patrons: Map[Long, String]) = Await.result(
      for {
        userData <- getUsers
        patronData <- getPatrons
      } yield (userData, patronData), 
    10.seconds)
```

Comment: You might get better performance by getting all the data in a single request. Add a log at the beginning and end of each future to see what takes the most time.

Comment: wait - where do you invoke he actual execution of your queries? In other words - where is your `db.run` in above code?

Comment: @PawelDolega sorry, forgot to put them in, code edited.

Comment: @nmat in the real case, loading one table took more time than the other. But if the assumption that "all the threads will be processed sequentially" is correct, I guess it wouldn't matter which take longer time.

Comment: @PawelDolega `run.toMap` added. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Uh... just realized... you are using Slick 2.x here, right?

Comment: @PawelDolega yes, slick 2.1.0